# Code Differences Between View Source and Debugger

Tags: html, debugging

I have a bug on my website where only on my 404 pages the very first heading in my footer would be rendered as a link when it is not suppose to. Investigating further, I've noticed that there are minor code differences between when I view the code via 'View Source' and the browser 'Debugger' (both Chrome and Firefox has produced the same code results). I am wondering what would cause these code differences. Shouldn't the 'View Source' and 'Debugger' output the same code?

Notice that the debugger inserts an `a` tag in `li.header`.

Output from View Source:

```
<div class="footer">
  <ul>
    <li class="header">Header Title</li>
    <li>Value01</li>
    <li>Value02</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Output from Debugger:

```
<div class="footer">
  <ul>
    <li class="header"><a href="#">Header Title</a></li>
    <li>Value01</li>
    <li>Value02</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Which *debugger* are you using over there?

Comment: IS there any script or anything running that might modify the dom? View source in a browser generally literally views the source, not the current state of the dom. The debugger would likely show the current state of the dom...

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools has two different tabs. `Elements` shows the current state of the DOM, `Sources` shows the original source.

Comment: @poitroae I'm using both Chrome debugger and Firebug.

Comment: @Chris I don't think there are any scripts that may modify this part of the DOM. I will confirm this though.

Comment: In Chrome, `Sources` should match `View Source`.

Comment: Another possibility is an extension is doing it.

Comment: @Barmar Extension... like a browser-based extension? I don't have any of these extensions installed on any of my development browsers.

Comment: I've disabled all of my JavaScript, but I still see the code discrepancy between the output from View Source and Debugger. Could there be anything else modifying my code?

Comment: Is this page in a location you could link to or is it a private site?

Comment: This page is located only on my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in my CMS as I didn't properly close an `a` tag in one of my text fields in the CMS, which caused this issue. Doing further research, it seems that View Source should display the current state of the code present on the page. The browser debugger, however, will try to fill in missing tags to make it more presentable (ie - in my case add that extra `a` tag).

Answer (score 1):

If the links aren't in the source it means they must be getting added by something else during or after page load. This will more than likely be done with JavaScript (this may be scripts included on the page *or* scripts which your browser Plugins and Extensions use), so chances are if you disable JavaScript this *problem* won't repeat itself.

The output from View Source will be the default content of the page - without any latter modifications.

The output from the Debugger will be the current content of the page - with any latter modifications.

Comment: Cool, let me investigate the JavaScript files.

Comment: I've disabled all of my JavaScript, but I still see the code discrepancy between the output from View Source and Debugger. Could there be anything else modifying my code?